# Definition of exact sequences in abelian category

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

In an abelian category, take two maps $A\xrightarrow {f} B\xrightarrow{g} C$ such that $g\circ f=0$. How do I prove that if $\text {Im} f \cong \text {Ker} g$, then $\text {Im} g \cong \text {Coker} f$? I see that, thinking of $\text {Im} g$ as  $\text {CokerKer} g$, there is a unique map $p:\text {Im} g \to \text {Coker} f$ and a unique map $ q:\text {Coker} f \to \text {Im} g $ such that $q\circ \text{Coker} f$ and $p\circ \text{Im} g$ ; however I don't see why their compositions are the identities.

Comment: It's actually $\mathrm{Coim}\,g=\mathrm{Coker}\,f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathrm{im}(f)=\mathrm{ker}(g)  \iff \mathrm{ker}(\mathrm{coker}(f))=\mathrm{ker}(g) \iff \mathrm{coker}(\mathrm{ker}(\mathrm{coker}(f)))=\mathrm{coker}(\mathrm{ker}(g)) \iff \mathrm{coker}(f)=\mathrm{coim}(g)$

Comment: Thank you, so in an abelian category your argument proves that the image of $g$ is the cokernel of $f$

Comment: Not the image, the coimage.

Comment: Image and coimage are isomorphic in an abelian category

Comment: Then I suppose we don't have the same concept of image and coimage.

Answer (score 1):

$g\circ f = 0$ implies that $\operatorname{im}f\subseteq \ker g$. Thus there is an induded map (descending to the quotient) $$\psi\colon B/{\operatorname{im} f} \to \operatorname{im} g$$

If $\operatorname{im}f = \ker g$ this implies $$\psi\colon B/{\operatorname{im}f} \xrightarrow{\cong} \operatorname{im} g$$

and since $B/{\operatorname{im}f} = \operatorname{coker} f$, we obtain

$$\psi\colon \operatorname{coker} f \xrightarrow{\cong} \operatorname{im} g.$$